# Need a shell script that bzip2's every single file recursively from a certain folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, zip

I know that this is really not my strong side to write those scripts.
I need a shell script which recursively packs every single file in its folder into the .bz2 format because I have a lot of files and when I do this manually it takes me hours.

For example here are alot of files(much more then this example):

```
/home/user/data/file1.yyy
/home/user/data/file2.xxx
/home/user/data/file3.zzz
/home/user/data/file4.txt
/home/user/data/file5.deb
/home/user/data/moredata/file1.xyz
/home/user/data/muchmoredata/file1.xyx
```

And I need them all formated into .bz2 like this:

```
/home/user/data/file1.yyy.bz2
/home/user/data/file2.xxx.bz2
/home/user/data/file3.zzz.bz2
/home/user/data/file4.txt.bz2
/home/user/data/file5.deb.bz2
/home/user/data/moredata/file1.xyz.bz2
/home/user/data/muchmoredata/file1.xyx.bz2
```

Another thing that would be great when at then end the script will run one times `chown -R example:example /home/user/data`

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bzip2` will accept multiple files as arguments on the command line. To solve your specific example, I would do

```
cd /home/user/
find . -type f | egrep -v '\.bz2' | xargs bzip2 -9 &
```

This will find all files under `/home/user`, exclude any already existing `.bz2` files from processing, and then send the remaining list via `xargs` to `bzip2`. The `-9` gives you maximum compression (but takes more time). There is no limit to the number or length of filenames that can be processed when using `xargs` to feed the command (in this case `bzip2`).

The `&` char means "run all of this in the background". This means the command prompt will return to you immediately, and you continue other work, but don't expect all the files to be compressed for a while. At some point you'll also get messages like 'Job %1 ... started' and later, 'Job %1 ... finished'.

As you asked for a script, we can also do this

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! -d "$1" ]] ; then
   echo "usage: b2zipper /path/to/dir/to/search" 1>&2
   exit 1
if
find "$1" -type f | egrep -v '\.bz2' | xargs bzip2 -9 &
```

Save this as `b2zipper`, and then make it executable with

```
chmod +x b2zipper
```

Comment: Wow, that's it.. I thought this will be at least 20 lines of code. Thank you! Im using the first simple ssh line cuz a script will here be kinda useless :D

Comment: It's the power of the `pipe` and of `xargs`! Glad it helped. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To build on accepted answer, an alternative would be:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -exec bzip2 {} \;
```